# Как правильно связать вью в ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

У меня есть такой XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                         android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/ll_frag_search_destination_header"
    layout="@layout/header_name_screen_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_frag_search_destination_header"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_view"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/cdll_frag_search_destination_input"
        layout="@layout/custom_edit_text_group"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </include>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cdll_frag_search_destination_input"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_frag_search_destination"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="250dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_frag_search_destination_clean_history"
            style="@style/Text_12sp.DarkBlue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:padding="@dimen/small_space"
            android:text="@string/clean_history"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="194dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="337dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:background="@color/midnight_blue_two"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Получается вот такой экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все вроде хорошо, до тех пор пока в `RecyclerView` элементов меньше чем высота экрана, но если элементов больше то получается так, что кнопка `Clean history` уезжает за предел экрана

вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно селать так, что даже если элементов больше чем помещается на экране то 
вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` изначально задумывался, как одноуровневый компоновщик (без вложенных в него других компоновочных контейнеров). Принцип такой, что соеденяем верхние элементы с верхом экрана, а нижние - с низом. Затем к этим элементам прикрепляем список.

Примерно как то так должно получится, разметка немного упрощена, но думаю вы разберетесь, где что должно находиться для вашего случая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Search"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clear"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Clear History"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```